# Python group by

Tags: python, group-by

Assume that I have a set of data pair where *index 0* is the value and *index 1* is the type:

```
input = [
          ('11013331', 'KAT'), 
          ('9085267',  'NOT'), 
          ('5238761',  'ETH'), 
          ('5349618',  'ETH'), 
          ('11788544', 'NOT'), 
          ('962142',   'ETH'), 
          ('7795297',  'ETH'), 
          ('7341464',  'ETH'), 
          ('9843236',  'KAT'), 
          ('5594916',  'ETH'), 
          ('1550003',  'ETH')
        ]
```

I want to group them by their type (by the 1st indexed string) as such:

```
result = [ 
           { 
             'type': 'KAT', 
             'items': ['11013331', '9843236'] 
           },
           {
             'type': 'NOT', 
             'items': ['9085267', '11788544'] 
           },
           {
             'type': 'ETH', 
             'items': ['5238761', '962142', '7795297', '7341464', '5594916', '1550003'] 
           }
         ]
```

How can I achieve this in an efficient way?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Do it in 2 steps. First, create a dictionary.

```
>>> input = [('11013331', 'KAT'), ('9085267', 'NOT'), ('5238761', 'ETH'), ('5349618', 'ETH'), ('11788544', 'NOT'), ('962142', 'ETH'), ('7795297', 'ETH'), ('7341464', 'ETH'), ('9843236', 'KAT'), ('5594916', 'ETH'), ('1550003', 'ETH')]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> res = defaultdict(list)
>>> for v, k in input: res[k].append(v)
...
```

Then, convert that dictionary into the expected format.

```
>>> [{'type':k, 'items':v} for k,v in res.items()]
[{'items': ['9085267', '11788544'], 'type': 'NOT'}, {'items': ['5238761', '5349618', '962142', '7795297', '7341464', '5594916', '1550003'], 'type': 'ETH'}, {'items': ['11013331', '9843236'], 'type': 'KAT'}]
```

---

It is also possible with itertools.groupby but it requires the input to be sorted first.

```
>>> sorted_input = sorted(input, key=itemgetter(1))
>>> groups = groupby(sorted_input, key=itemgetter(1))
>>> [{'type':k, 'items':[x[0] for x in v]} for k, v in groups]
[{'items': ['5238761', '5349618', '962142', '7795297', '7341464', '5594916', '1550003'], 'type': 'ETH'}, {'items': ['11013331', '9843236'], 'type': 'KAT'}, {'items': ['9085267', '11788544'], 'type': 'NOT'}]
```

---

Note: before **python 3.7**, both of these do not respect the original order of the keys. You need an OrderedDict if you need to keep the order.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> res = OrderedDict()
>>> for v, k in input:
...   if k in res: res[k].append(v)
...   else: res[k] = [v]
... 
>>> [{'type':k, 'items':v} for k,v in res.items()]
[{'items': ['11013331', '9843236'], 'type': 'KAT'}, {'items': ['9085267', '11788544'], 'type': 'NOT'}, {'items': ['5238761', '5349618', '962142', '7795297', '7341464', '5594916', '1550003'], 'type': 'ETH'}]
```

On or after python 3.7, a regular dict keeps insertion order.

Comment: How can this be done if the input tuple has one key and two or more values, like this: `[('11013331', 'red', 'KAT'), ('9085267', 'blue' 'KAT')]` where the last element of tuple is key and the first two as value. Result should be like this:

result = [{
    type:'KAT', items: [('11013331', red), ('9085267', blue)] }]

Comment: `from operator import itemgetter`

Comment: step 1 can be done without the import: `d= {}; for k,v in input: d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)`

Comment: I'm working on a MapReduce program in python, just wondering is there any way to group by values in a list without dealing with dictionaries or external library such as pandas? If not, then how can I get rid of items and type in my result?

Answer (score 81):

Python's built-in `itertools` module actually has a [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function , but for that the elements to be grouped must first be sorted such that the elements to be grouped are contiguous in the list:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sortkeyfn = itemgetter(1)
input = [('11013331', 'KAT'), ('9085267', 'NOT'), ('5238761', 'ETH'), 
 ('5349618', 'ETH'), ('11788544', 'NOT'), ('962142', 'ETH'), ('7795297', 'ETH'), 
 ('7341464', 'ETH'), ('9843236', 'KAT'), ('5594916', 'ETH'), ('1550003', 'ETH')] 
input.sort(key=sortkeyfn)
```

Now input looks like:

```
[('5238761', 'ETH'), ('5349618', 'ETH'), ('962142', 'ETH'), ('7795297', 'ETH'),
 ('7341464', 'ETH'), ('5594916', 'ETH'), ('1550003', 'ETH'), ('11013331', 'KAT'),
 ('9843236', 'KAT'), ('9085267', 'NOT'), ('11788544', 'NOT')]
```

`groupby` returns a sequence of 2-tuples, of the form `(key, values_iterator)`.  What we want is to turn this into a list of dicts where the 'type' is the key, and 'items' is a list of the 0'th elements of the tuples returned by the values_iterator.  Like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
result = []
for key,valuesiter in groupby(input, key=sortkeyfn):
    result.append(dict(type=key, items=list(v[0] for v in valuesiter)))
```

Now `result` contains your desired dict, as stated in your question.

You might consider, though, just making a single dict out of this, keyed by type, and each value containing the list of values.  In your current form, to find the values for a particular type, you'll have to iterate over the list to find the dict containing the matching 'type' key, and then get the 'items' element from it.  If you use a single dict instead of a list of 1-item dicts, you can find the items for a particular type with a single keyed lookup into the master dict.  Using `groupby`, this would look like:

```
result = {}
for key,valuesiter in groupby(input, key=sortkeyfn):
    result[key] = list(v[0] for v in valuesiter)
```

`result` now contains this dict (this is similar to the intermediate `res` defaultdict in @KennyTM's answer):

```
{'NOT': ['9085267', '11788544'], 
 'ETH': ['5238761', '5349618', '962142', '7795297', '7341464', '5594916', '1550003'], 
 'KAT': ['11013331', '9843236']}
```

(If you want to reduce this to a one-liner, you can:

```
result = dict((key,list(v[0] for v in valuesiter)
              for key,valuesiter in groupby(input, key=sortkeyfn))
```

or using the newfangled dict-comprehension form:

```
result = {key:list(v[0] for v in valuesiter)
              for key,valuesiter in groupby(input, key=sortkeyfn)}
```

Comment: I'm working on a MapReduce program in python, just wondering is there any way to group by values in a list without dealing with dictionaries or external library such as pandas? If not, then how can I get rid of items and type in my result?

Comment: @Kourosh -  Post as a new question, but be sure to indicate what you mean by "get rid of items and type in my result", and "without dealing with dictionaries".

Comment: The first example -result=[] - is a list, inside a dict and values in a list. The second - result ={} - is a dict and values in a list. Smart the way you improved the code.

Answer (score 21):

This answer is similar to [@PaulMcG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3749740/1056941) but doesn't require sorting the input.

For those into functional programming, `groupBy` can be written in one line (not including imports!), and unlike `itertools.groupby` it doesn't require the input to be sorted:

```py
from functools import reduce # import needed for python3; builtin in python2
from collections import defaultdict

def groupBy(key, seq):
 return reduce(lambda grp, val: grp[key(val)].append(val) or grp, seq, defaultdict(list))
```

(The reason for `... or grp` in the `lambda` is that for this `reduce()` to work, the `lambda` needs to return its first argument; because `list.append()` always returns `None` the `or` will always return `grp`.  I.e. it's a hack to get around python's restriction that a lambda can only evaluate a single expression.)

This returns a dict whose keys are found by evaluating the given function and whose values are a list of the original items in the original order.  For the OP's example, calling this as `groupBy(lambda pair: pair[1], input)` will return this dict:

```py
{'KAT': [('11013331', 'KAT'), ('9843236', 'KAT')],
 'NOT': [('9085267', 'NOT'), ('11788544', 'NOT')],
 'ETH': [('5238761', 'ETH'), ('5349618', 'ETH'), ('962142', 'ETH'), ('7795297', 'ETH'), ('7341464', 'ETH'), ('5594916', 'ETH'), ('1550003', 'ETH')]}
```

And as per [@PaulMcG's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3749740/1056941) the OP's requested format can be found by wrapping that in a list comprehension.  So this will do it:

```py
result = {key: [pair[0] for pair in values],
          for key, values in groupBy(lambda pair: pair[1], input).items()}
```

Comment: A lot less code, yet understandable.  Also good because it doesn't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This solution also works as `groupBy`, that is -- it can accept a callable as a key too.  Very handy.

Answer (score 11):

I also liked pandas simple [grouping](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html). it's powerful, simple and most adequate for large data set

```py
result = pandas.DataFrame(input).groupby(1).groups
```

Answer (score 3):

The following function will quickly (**no sorting** required) group tuples of any length by a key having any index:

```
# given a sequence of tuples like [(3,'c',6),(7,'a',2),(88,'c',4),(45,'a',0)],
# returns a dict grouping tuples by idx-th element - with idx=1 we have:
# if merge is True {'c':(3,6,88,4),     'a':(7,2,45,0)}
# if merge is False {'c':((3,6),(88,4)), 'a':((7,2),(45,0))}
def group_by(seqs,idx=0,merge=True):
    d = dict()
    for seq in seqs:
        k = seq[idx]
        v = d.get(k,tuple()) + (seq[:idx]+seq[idx+1:] if merge else (seq[:idx]+seq[idx+1:],))
        d.update({k:v})
    return d
```

In the case of your question, the index of key you want to group by is 1, therefore:

```
group_by(input,1)
```

gives

```
{'ETH': ('5238761','5349618','962142','7795297','7341464','5594916','1550003'),
 'KAT': ('11013331', '9843236'),
 'NOT': ('9085267', '11788544')}
```

which is not exactly the output you asked for, but might as well suit your needs.

Comment: I'm working on a MapReduce program in python, just wondering is there any way to group by values in a list without dealing with dictionaries or external library such as pandas? If not, then how can I get rid of items and type in my result?

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
# Make a set of your "types":
input_set = set([tpl[1] for tpl in input])
>>> set(['ETH', 'KAT', 'NOT'])
# Iterate over the input_set
for type_ in input_set:
    # a dict to gather things:
    D = {}
    # filter all tuples from your input with the same type as type_
    tuples = filter(lambda tpl: tpl[1] == type_, input)
    # write them in the D:
    D["type"] = type_
    D["itmes"] = [tpl[0] for tpl in tuples]
    # append D to results:
    result.append(D)

result
>>> [{'itmes': ['9085267', '11788544'], 'type': 'NOT'}, {'itmes': ['5238761', '5349618', '962142', '7795297', '7341464', '5594916', '1550003'], 'type': 'ETH'}, {'itmes': ['11013331', '9843236'], 'type': 'KAT'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library which generates ad-hoc code for your exact task and allows for dynamic code generation.

```py
from convtools import conversion as c

# grouping by second elements of tuples;
# aggregate defines the schema of the expected output elements
converter = c.group_by(c.item(1)).aggregate({
    "type": c.item(1),
    "items": c.ReduceFuncs.Array(c.item(0)),
}).gen_converter()

# now you have a function which does what you asked,
# store it somewhere for further reuse
converter(input_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Snippet is also a way to get the desired results -

```
res = []
dict1 = {}
for item in input:
  if item[1] not in dict1:
    dict1[item[1]] = [item[0]]
  elif item[1] in dict1:
    dict1[item[1]].append(item[0])
for k, v in dict1.items():
  res.append({"type": k, "items": v})


# res = [ { type:'KAT', items: ['11013331', '9843236'] },{ type:'NOT',  items: ['9085267', '11788544'] },{ type:'ETH',  items: ['5238761', '962142', '7795297', '7341464', '5594916', '1550003'] }]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not very efficient, but it is Pythonic. Basically, work out the distinct groups by taking the set of group values, and then for each of these groups, get the items that are in that group.

```
[
    {
        "type": group,
        "items": [item[0] for item in input if item[1] == group]
    }
    for group in {item[1] for item in input}
]
```