# Best way to sort a dictionary into groups using Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of dictionaries eg:

```
[{'person':'guybrush','job':'pirate'},{'person':'leChuck','job':'pirate'}, {'person':'elaine','job':'governor'}]
```

I want to display the people grouped by their jobs. So in the front end, we can select a job and see all of the people that have the selected job.

I have performed such a function before using confusing nested loops and lists.

What do you think is the most efficient way of getting this result?

```
pirate = ['guybrush','leChuck']
governor = ['elaine']
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by)

Comment: you are right, it does look like Ive duplicated a question. Sorry!

Comment: What does agile have to do with it?

Comment: Well, rather than creating a previously defined set of lists, let the lists be created dynamically.

Comment: @JackalopeZero: The word agile has a [special meaning](http://agilemanifesto.org/) in the context of software development, hence some people might be confused by the way you used it there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is simple using a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
persons_by_jobs = defaultdict(list)
for person in persons:
    persons_by_jobs[person['job']].append(person['person'])
```

Comment: just curious @Björn Pollex What made you choose this over a groupby operation?

Comment: If you are talking about [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), it requires the list to already be sorted by the grouping predicate. This means we'd need two passes over the data, one for sorting, and one for grouping. I think the solution I've presented here is simpler, and likely more efficient.

Comment: what if I also want to sort it, within each job, (let's say descending order, coz here it is ascending by default) say I want to get this result: `governor = ['elaine'] pirate = ['leChuck','guybrush']`