# python dictionary, how convert it

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a question about the accepted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3749512/1082727) question.

Could you explain why this code:

```
[{'type':k, 'items':v} for k,v in res.items()]
```

do the job, i.e. it combines items to list in with same key.

Comment: This question is poor, please clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Could you explain `[{'type':k, 'items':v} for k,v in res.items()]`

Let's take it apart:

1. `for k,v in res.items()` iterates over the entries of `res`, assigning each key and value  to `k` and `v` respectively.
2. `{'type':k, 'items':v}` creates a two-element dictionary. The first element has key `'type'` and value `k`; the second element has key `'items'` and value `v`.
3. The effect of the list comprehension `[...]` is that each entry in `res` gets converted into a dictionary as explained in step 2, and the resulting dictionaries are stored in a list.

Answer (score 3):

The brackets around the expression make this a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Basically, the left part (`{'type':k, 'items':v}`) is evaluated for each item, and the result is made a list.

[`res.items`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) returns tuples of key and value for each entry in the dictionary.

Say that the input `res` is `{'a': 7, 'b': 9}` (that's a dictionary that maps `a` to `7` and `b` to `9`. Then, `res.items()` is:

```
[('a', 7), ('b', 9)]
```

The round braces make a tuple, which is basically an immutable list. The for loop in the list comprehension iterates over the elements of the tuple, and temporarily assigns them to `k` and `v`:

```
# First iteration
k = 'a'
v = 7
=> Add {'type': 'a', 'items': 7} to the result

# First iteration
k = 'b'
v = 9
=> Add {'type': 'b', 'items': 9} to the result
```

Now, the result is the list

```
[{'type': 'a', 'items': 7}, {'type': 'b', 'items': 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[{'type':k, 'items':v} for k,v in res.items()]
```

It means exactly what it appears to mean: "A list consisting of (a dictionary that looks like: `{'type': k, 'items': v}`), for each `k, v` pair contained in `res.items()`".