# Read a file and output new files containing subsets of main file

Tags: python, text

I have a text file that contains rows of data. I want to use python to create new smaller text files that each contain a specified subset of this main text file. Each new file should be named after a string in column 3 and the file should contain all lines that contain that string in column 3 but should have column 3 itself excluded, as that information is now stored in the name of the file. My main problem is how to specify the last column as the string to be used for the file name.

example of input text file:

```
chr8:200-300    Gene1
chr8:400-500    Gene1
chr4:50-60  Gene2
chr4:90-200 Gene2
chr8:30-400 Gene3
chr8:9618-9749  Gene4
```

example of desired output file called Gene2.txt:

```
chr4:50-60
chr4:90-200
```

Comment: Stack overflow users are required to do some research effort. As currently stated it is likely to be closed as "too broad" (even if it is not that broad). Amend your question showing some research effort and flag it for reopening.

Comment: A hint to get started, regex's are good for dicing things up: `re.match(r"([^:]+):([^\s]+)\s+(.*)", "chr8:200-300    Gene1").groups()` gives you `('chr8', '200-300', 'Gene1')` making that 3rd item easily available for a file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users commented, if you use a dictionary you can iterate over the values.

```
with open("path/to/file.txt","r") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        content,gene  = line.strip().split()
        if d.has_key(gene):
            d[gene].append(content)
        else:
            d[gene] = []
            d[gene].append(content)

    for key,value in d.iteritems():
        f = open("path/to/destination/{}.txt".format(key), "w")
        for item in value:    
            f.write("{}\n".format(item))
        f.close()
```

Comment: works beautifully thank you!

Comment: if there are 4 columns in the data, how would I modify this so that first 3 columns are outputted and last column is the gene name used for the filename?

Comment: Do you have an example of how the new data looks like?

Comment: actually I half solved it with this:  " fields  = line.strip().split("\t")
      content = fields[0:3]
      gene = fields[3] " However the content of the files still has all the formatting like "[ ' ' ]" around the three columns of data. So question is just how to print the data without this python formatting

Comment: example output: ['chr4', '187363347', '187363450'] would prefer: chr4 187363347 187363450 (tab separated)

Comment: if i understand what yo are saying, i think if you use the join() fucntion you can do something like `b = " \t".join(item)` then write b to the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69754/discussion-between-user964689-and-daniel).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by:

1. Read the input lines and split the columns.
2. Create a Dictionary that maps the name to an array of items. Insert each input line into the dictionary.
3. Iterate over the dictionary. For each dictionary item, write a file using the dictionary key as the filename and the array as the file contents.

See [Python group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by)