# How to convert a tuple list with duplicated keys and values into a fancy dicionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a tuple list like the code below, an identifier has multiple values(both identifier and values maybe duplicated), I thought using `dict` with a `str` as a key and a `set` as it's value would be reasonable, but how?

```
tuple_list = [
    ('id1', 123),
    ('id1', 123),
    ('id2', 123),
    ('id1', 456),
    ('id2', 456),
    ('id1', 789),
    ('id2', 789)
]
```

What I need is like this: `{ 'id1': {123, 456, 789}`, ... }`, my code is:

```
for id, val in tuple_list:
    map_data[id].append(val) # error here, how to fix this?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python group by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by) or [How do I use Python's itertools.groupby()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-pythons-itertools-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a `dict` containing a `set` do it like this.

```
from collections import defaultdict

tuple_list = [
    ('id1', 123),
    ('id1', 123),
    ('id2', 123),
    ('id1', 456),
    ('id2', 456),
    ('id1', 789),
    ('id2', 789)
]

map_data = defaultdict(set)

for id, val in tuple_list:
    map_data[id].add(val)

print(map_data)
```

result

```
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'id2': set([456, 123, 789]), 'id1': set([456, 123, 789])})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setdefaultdict`:

```
map_data = {}
for id, val in tuple_list:
    map_data.setdefault(id,set()).add(val)
```

Comment: OP wants a set not a list.

Comment: Apologies for the format, I've modified it, thank you.