# break list into sublist on some condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list as follows -

```
[
    {     
      "ques_id": "154",
      "cat_id": "1",     
    },
    {     
      "ques_id": "155",
      "cat_id": "1",     
    },
    {     
      "ques_id": "156",
      "cat_id": "2",     
    },
    {     
      "ques_id": "157",
      "cat_id": "2",     
    }]
```

i want sublists as follows -

```
[
    {     
      "ques_id": "154",
      "cat_id": "1",     
    },
    {     
      "ques_id": "155",
      "cat_id": "1",     
    }
]
```

and

```
   [{     
      "ques_id": "156",
      "cat_id": "2",     
    },
    {     
      "ques_id": "157",
      "cat_id": "2",     
    }]
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: no it didn't help

Comment: Sorry, typo, meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by#3749537

Comment: no i want the output in same format i have specified as there will be more key value pairs , but filtering is on basis of cat_id only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you want to split the list on certain property like say cat_id. 
Can we assume that you know the total cat ids?
Say they are 1 an 2

Then you can do

```
list_1 = [x for x in list if x["cat_id"] == 1]
list_2 = [x for x in list if x["cat_id"] == 2]
```

In a more general case where you don't know the possible values of cat_id you need to first find all the ids.

```
ids = [x["cat_id"] for x in list]
ids = list(set(ids))
```

Now finally lists

```
lists = [[ x for x in list if x["cat_id"] == y ] for y in ids ]
```

This will give you a list of lists.

Comment: cat_id is not known in beginning , it may be any number , let me try your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this since this is a list you can use list slicing to breack according to your desire. Since you didn't specify upon what condition you need to break list i assume that you want to split it into half from your question then the answer will be

```
list1 = [
    {     
      "ques_id": "154",
      "cat_id": "1",     
    },
    {     
      "ques_id": "155",
      "cat_id": "1",     
    },
    {     
      "ques_id": "156",
      "cat_id": "2",     
    },
    {     
      "ques_id": "157",
      "cat_id": "2",     
    }]

print (list1[:len(list1)/2]) #this gives you 1st half
print (list1[len(list1)/2:]) #this gives you second half.
```

**Note : For cases len(list) is odd. Ex if len(list) is 11 then first half length will be 5 and last half will be 6**

The same logic can be applied according to your needs.

Comment: number of elements if not fixed

Comment: It will work for list of all length for length 0 it will also work giving you []

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon my comment, it is possible to use a technique similar to that presented in [Python group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by#3749537)

```
from collections import defaultdict
data =[...]
tmp = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    tmp[item["cat_id"]].append(item)
res = list(tmp.values())
```