# Join n-lists that have the first equal value in Python

Tags: python, list

I should join all the lists that have the first value in common in one and only list that contains, that value (without repeating) plus all the others:

```
[
  ['time', 'free'],
  ['time', 'first'],
  ['visit', 'last'],
  ['city', 'small'],
  ['city', 'entire'],
  ['world', 'surreal'],
  ['world', 'amazing'],
]
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
[
  ['time','free','first'],
  ['visit','last'],
  ['city','small', 'entire'],
  ['world','surreal', 'amazing'],
]
```

if possible I would not use modules because it is a univeristary project.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these lists sorted/grouped by first element?

Comment: yes, they are sorted by first element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple loop solution, start a new group as necessary:

```
groups = []
for a, b in items:
    if not groups or a != groups[-1][0]:
        groups.append([a])
    groups[-1].append(b)
```

And a dict solution inspired by the others (this might "shuffle" the result list unless you use CPython 3.6+ or another Python that keeps dicts in insertion order):

```
d = {}
for a, b in items:
    d.setdefault(a, [a]).append(b)
groups = list(d.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your sub-lists are grouped by the first element, your solution simplifies, using `itertools.groupby`.

```
r = [[i] + [y[1] for y in g] for i, g in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

```
print(r)
[['time', 'free', 'first'],
 ['visit', 'last'],
 ['city', 'small', 'entire'],
 ['world', 'surreal', 'amazing']]
```

Where `l` is your list. What we're doing here is

1. grouping by the first element
2. for each group, extract the second element from each row and form a list.

The loop equivalent of this would be -

```
r = []
for for i, g in itertools.groupby(l, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    i = [i]                 # converting the string key to a list
    j = [y[1] for y in g]   # extracting the second element from the `grouper` object

    r.append(i + j)         # concatenating `i` and `j` and adding it to our result
```

---

For kicks, here's the pandas equivalent of this function. The idiom is the same - split + apply + combine.

```
v = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['A', 'B'])\
           .groupby('A', sort=False).B.apply(list)

r = pd.DataFrame(v.tolist(), index=v.index).reset_index().values.tolist()
```

```
print(r)
[['time', 'free', 'first'],
 ['visit', 'last', None],
 ['city', 'small', 'entire'],
 ['world', 'surreal', 'amazing']]
```

Comment: Downvoter, please let me know if there's something lacking with this answer. I'd love to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the reason for downvoting -- `groupby` is the way to go here. +1.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, using `dict` is by its design good one, also easily readable:

```
l = [
    ['time', 'free'],
    ['time', 'first'],
    ['visit', 'last'],
    ['city', 'small'],
    ['city', 'entire'],
    ['world', 'surreal'],
    ['world', 'amazing'],
]

d = dict()
for item in l:
    try:
        d[item[0]] += item[1:]
    except KeyError:
        d[item[0]] = item[1:]

result = [[key] + value for key, value in d.items()]
print(result)  # [['time', 'free', 'first'], ['visit', 'last'], ['city', 'small', 'entire'], ['world', 'surreal', 'amazing']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using OrderedDict preserving order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = [
  ['time', 'free'],
  ['time', 'first'],
  ['visit', 'last'],
  ['city', 'small'],
  ['city', 'entire'],
  ['world', 'surreal'],
  ['world', 'amazing'],
]

d = OrderedDict()

for k,v in l:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

output = [[k]+v for k,v in d.items()]
```

---

And using pandas (simply because :))

```
import pandas as pd

l = [
  ['time', 'free'],
  ['time', 'first'],
  ['visit', 'last'],
  ['city', 'small'],
  ['city', 'entire'],
  ['world', 'surreal'],
  ['world', 'amazing'],
]

output = [[k]+v for k,v in pd.DataFrame(l).groupby(0)[1].apply(list).to_dict().items()]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
s = [
 ['time', 'free'],
 ['time', 'first'],
 ['visit', 'last'],
 ['city', 'small'],
 ['city', 'entire'],
 ['world', 'surreal'],
 ['world', 'amazing'],
]
new_data = [[[a]+[b for c, b in list(b)]][0] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

Output:

```
[['city', 'small', 'entire'], ['time', 'free', 'first'], ['visit', 'last'], ['world', 'surreal', 'amazing']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, but no libraries used:

```
l = [...] # Your list
d = {}

for key, value in l:
    if key in d:
        d[key].append(value)
    else:
        d[key] = [value]

print([[key] + value for key, value in d.items()])
```

This basically stores the first item as the dictionary key, and the second item in the list is appended to a list in the correspondent key (first item).

Then the last line flattens the dictionary and prints it.

Comment: Nice, but I prefer the `setdefault` version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48084433/842935

Comment: You could simplify the `if...else` to: `d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
data=[
  ['time', 'free'],
  ['time', 'first'],
  ['visit', 'last'],
  ['city', 'small'],
  ['city', 'entire'],
  ['world', 'surreal'],
  ['world', 'amazing'],
]


group={}

for i in data:
    if i[0] not in group:
        group[i[0]]=i
    else:
        group[i[0]].extend([i[1]])

print(group.values())
```

If order doesn't matter then you can try this :

```
data=[
  ['time', 'free'],
  ['time', 'first'],
  ['visit', 'last'],
  ['city', 'small'],
  ['city', 'entire'],
  ['world', 'surreal'],
  ['world', 'amazing'],
]


group={}

for i in data:
    if i[0] not in group:
        group[i[0]]=i
    else:
        group[i[0]].extend(i)

print(list(map(lambda x:set(group[x]),group.keys())))
```

output:

```
[{'surreal', 'amazing', 'world'}, {'entire', 'small', 'city'}, {'free', 'time', 'first'}, {'last', 'visit'}]
```

Default dict version: