# Group python list of dictionaries by values

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

Given I have a list of dictionaries I want to create new list of lists grouping the dictionaries by the values of "price":

```
dicts = [
     { "name": "item1", "price": 10 },
     { "name": "item2", "price": 5 },
     { "name": "item3", "price": 10 },
     { "name": "item4", "price": 12 },
     { "name": "item5", "price": 12 },
     { "name": "item6", "price": 5 }
 ]
```

Should create:

```
grouped_dicts = [
     [{ "name": "item1", "price": 10 },
     { "name": "item3", "price": 10 }],
     [{ "name": "item2", "price": 5 },
     { "name": "item6", "price": 5 }],
     [{ "name": "item4", "price": 12 },
     { "name": "item5", "price": 12 }]
]
```

Is there a nice way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I want to group/create a new list of lists containing dictionaries where "price" matches. Make sence?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to make a dictionary mapping prices to lists of dictionaries, then taking the `.values()` of that dictionary.  You can see a similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58139585/4058364), here is how you do it without an additional import:

```
d = {}

for item in dicts:
    d.setdefault(item['price'], []).append(item)

list(d.values())
```

Out:

```
[[{'name': 'item1', 'price': 10}, {'name': 'item3', 'price': 10}],
 [{'name': 'item2', 'price': 5}, {'name': 'item6', 'price': 5}],
 [{'name': 'item4', 'price': 12}, {'name': 'item5', 'price': 12}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `deaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d=defaultdict(list)
for item in dicts:
        d[list(item.values())[-1]].append(item)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {10: [{'name': 'item1', 'price': 10},
              {'name': 'item3', 'price': 10}],
             5: [{'name': 'item2', 'price': 5}, {'name': 'item6', 'price': 5}],
             12: [{'name': 'item4', 'price': 12},
              {'name': 'item5', 'price': 12}]})
```

If you just need the list then just extract the values of defaultdict

```
list(d.values())
```

Output:

```
[[{'name': 'item1', 'price': 10}, {'name': 'item3', 'price': 10}],
 [{'name': 'item2', 'price': 5}, {'name': 'item6', 'price': 5}],
 [{'name': 'item4', 'price': 12}, {'name': 'item5', 'price': 12}]]
```

Comment: Thank you. But this groups by "name" and not "price"?

Comment: @Max How is it grouping by name?

Comment: Am I doing it wrong?

>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in dicts:
...         d[list(item.values())[-1]].append(item) 
... 
>>> list(d.values())
[[{'price': 5, 'name': 'item2'}], [{'price': 10, 'name': 'item3'}], [{'price': 10, 'name': 'item1'}], [{'price': 5, 'name': 'item6'}], [{'price': 12, 'name': 'item4'}], [{'price': 12, 'name': 'item5'}]]

Comment: `setDefault` and `defaultDict` works pretty much in same fashion. defaultdict is like saying for all keys I want values to be list while for setdefault you need to set for each key but logically they can be same like in this case