# List of dict to list of nested dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by, nested

I have `input_data` like this:

```
input_data = [
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'foo1',  'qty': 100},
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'foo1', 'qty': 200},
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'baz1', 'qty': 300},
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'baz1', 'qty': 400},
        {'vehicle': '002', 'store': 'foo2', 'qty': 500},
        {'vehicle': '002', 'store': 'baz2', 'qty': 600},
        {'vehicle': '002', 'store': 'baz2', 'qty': 700}]
```

What is the best way in Python to have the `out_put` data look like as follows:

```
output_data = [{'vehicle': '001',
            'store': [{'store': 'foo1', 'qty': [100, 200]},
                      {'store': 'baz1', 'qty': [300, 400]},
                      ]
            },
           {'vehicle': '002',
            'store': [{'store': 'foo2', 'qty': [500]},
                      {'store': 'baz2', 'qty': [600, 700]},
                      ]
            }]
```

Comment: Your code please

Comment: similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, I am sure there's an elegant way, but can't figure it out at the moment:

```
import pandas as pd

input_data = [
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'foo1',  'qty': 100},
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'foo1', 'qty': 200},
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'baz1', 'qty': 300},
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'baz1', 'qty': 400},
        {'vehicle': '002', 'store': 'foo2', 'qty': 500},
        {'vehicle': '002', 'store': 'baz2', 'qty': 600},
        {'vehicle': '002', 'store': 'baz2', 'qty': 700}]
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(input_data).groupby(['vehicle','store'])['qty'].apply(list))
dct = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: df.xs(df.name)['qty'].to_dict()).to_dict()
final_list = []
for k in dct:
    temp_dct = {}
    temp_dct['vehicle'] = k
    temp_l = [dict(zip(['store','qty'],[key,v])) for key,v in dct[k].items()]
    temp_dct['store'] = temp_l
    final_list.append(temp_dct)
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'vehicle': '001',
  'store': [{'qty': [300, 400], 'store': 'baz1'},
            {'qty': [100, 200], 'store': 'foo1'}]},
 {'vehicle': '002',
  'store': [{'qty': [600, 700], 'store': 'baz2'},
            {'qty': [500], 'store': 'foo2'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `operator.itemgetter`

```
names = v, s, q = 'vehicle', 'store', 'qty'
v_key, s_key, q_key = map(itemgetter, names)
output_data = [{v: {s: [{s: sk, q: list(map(q_key, sv))}
                            for sk, sv in groupby(vv, s_key)]}}
                            for vk, vv in groupby(input_data, v_key)]
```

Results:

```
[{'vehicle': {'store': [{'qty': [100, 200], 'store': 'foo1'},
                        {'qty': [300, 400], 'store': 'baz1'}]}},
 {'vehicle': {'store': [{'qty': [500], 'store': 'foo2'},
                        {'qty': [600, 700], 'store': 'baz2'}]}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it with inbuilt `itertools - groupby method`:

```
# Input data
input_data = [
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'foo1',  'qty': 100},
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'foo1', 'qty': 200},
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'baz1', 'qty': 300},
        {'vehicle': '001', 'store': 'baz1', 'qty': 400},
        {'vehicle': '002', 'store': 'foo2', 'qty': 500},
        {'vehicle': '002', 'store': 'baz2', 'qty': 600},
        {'vehicle': '002', 'store': 'baz2', 'qty': 700}]

# Main code
from itertools import groupby # For grouping a dataset

data = groupby(input_data, key = lambda x: x['vehicle']) # Grouping vehicles

final_data = []
for i in data:
    inner = {}
    outer = {}
    for j in list(i[1]):
        inner.setdefault(j['store'], []).append(j['qty'])
    outer["vehicle"] = i[0]
    outer["store"] = [{"store":i, "qty": j} for i, j in inner.items()]
    final_data.append(outer)

print (final_data)

# Output
# {'vehicle': '001', 'store': [{'store': 'foo1', 'qty': [100, 200]}, {'store': 'baz1', 'qty': [300, 400]}]}, {'vehicle': '002', 'store': [{'store': 'foo2', 'qty': [500]}, {'store': 'baz2', 'qty': [600, 700]}]}]
```

I hope this helps and counts!

Answer (score 0):

Below code produces expected output:

result_list=[]
def check_duplicate(vehicle_name):
    for index,d in enumerate(result_list):
        if d.get("vehicle")==vehicle_name:
            return True,index
        for store_index ,store_value in enumerate(d.get("store")):
            if store_value.get("store")==vehicle_name:
                return True,store_index

```
return False,None
```

for data in input_data:

```
if isinstance(data,dict) and  data.has_key("vehicle"):
    #print data
    result= check_duplicate(data.get('vehicle'))
    if not result[0]:
        result_list.append({'vehicle':data.get('vehicle'),'store':[{'store':data.get('store') , 'qty': [data.get('qty')]}]})

    if result[0]:
        print "check if store is already present"
        store_check= check_duplicate(data.get('store'))

        if store_check[0]:
            result_list[result[1]].get("store")[store_check[1]].get("qty").append(data.get('qty'))
        if not store_check[0]:
            result_list[result[1]].get("store").append({'store':data.get('store') , 'qty': [data.get('qty')]})
```

print result_list