# Addition 2 lists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list :

```
A = [[33, 0], [34, 0], [35, 5], [36, 0], [38, 0], [39, 0], [40, 0], [41, 0], [42, 0], [43, 0], [44, 0], [45, 1], [46, 0], [47, 0], [48, 0], [49, 0], [50, 0], [51, 1], [52, 0], [56, 0], [57, 0], [58, 0], [59, 0], [62, 1]]
```

And a second list :

```
B = [[35, 1], [35, 2], [35, 1], [35, 2], [35, 0], [45, 7], [51, 0], [62, 0]]
```

My goal is to create the list C like :

```
if A[0] = B[0] :
  do A[1] + B[1]
```

The result should be :

```
C = [[33, 0], [34, 0], [35, 11], [36, 0], [38, 0], [39, 0], [40, 0], [41, 0], [42, 0], [43, 0], [44, 0], [45, 8], [46, 0], [47, 0], [48, 0], [49, 0], [50, 0], [51, 1], [52, 0], [56, 0], [57, 0], [58, 0], [59, 0], [62, 1]]
```

Hope it's understanding. I don't know how to write it properly in Python.

Comment: Could you explain your algorithm for adding the two lists together better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by)

Comment: Why is the third item `[35, 11]` and not `[35, 6]` ?

Comment: The two lists have not equal length. And what should happen if `A[0]!=B[0]`?

Comment: @OmarAflak, it seems he's adding all the B's that have B[0]==35. Some kind of a bucket sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C=[]
for a in A:
    c = a.copy()
    for b in B:
        if b[0] == a[0]:
            c[1] += b[1]
    C.append(c)
```

Or, using list comprehensions:

```
C = [[a[0], a[1] + sum(b[1] for b in B if b[0] == a[0])] for a in A]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to sum B, then add that to A.

```
from collections import Counter

d = Counter()
for x, count in B:
    d[x] += count

C = [[y, count+d[y]] for y, count in A]
```

Afterwards:

```
>>> C
[[33, 0], [34, 0], [35, 11], [36, 0], [38, 0], [39, 0], [40, 0], [41, 0], [42, 0], [43, 0], [44, 0], [45, 8], [46, 0], [47, 0], [48, 0], [49, 0], [50, 0], [51, 1], [52, 0], [56, 0], [57, 0], [58, 0], [59, 0], [62, 1]]
>>> [c for c in C if c[1] != 0]  # The interesting bits
[[35, 11], [45, 8], [51, 1], [62, 1]]
>>> d
Counter({35: 6, 45: 7, 51: 0, 62: 0})
```

You could also use `defaultdict(int)` instead, but I think `Counter` is the more natural fit here. As well, a `defaultdict` would be mutated just by looking up a non-existent element (e.g. `d[33]`), which IMO is not ideal.