# Python dictionary parent child organization

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have a `list` like this

```
laptop_list = [
{"manufacturer_id": 1 , "manufacturer_name": "Lenovo", "model_number": 000000, "model_name": "Legion"}, 
{"manufacturer_id": 1 , "manufacturer_name": "Lenovo", "model_number": 999999, "model_name": "Ideapad"}, 
{"manufacturer_id": 2 , "manufacturer_name": "HP", "model_number": 0101010, "model_name": "pavillion"} ,
{"manufacturer_id": 2 , "manufacturer_name": "HP", "model_number": 0202020, "model_name": "Inspiron"} ]
```

I need to re-structure the above list similar to

```
[{"manufacturer_id": 1 , "manufacturer_name": "Lenovo", "models":[{"model_number": 000000, "model_name": "Legion"}, {"model_number": 999999, "model_name": "Ideapad"}]},
{"manufacturer_id": 2 , "manufacturer_name": "HP", "models":[{"model_number": 0101010, "model_name": "pavillion"} , {"model_number": 0202020, "model_name": "Inspiron"}]} ]
```

I tried using a `node` class but couldn't achieve the desired result

```
class LaptopNode:

    def __init__(self, manufacturer_id, manufacturer_name):
        self.manufacturer_id = manufacturer_id
        self.manufacturer_name = manufacturer_name
        self.child_models = []
```

Can anyone please suggest an efficient way to achieve this ?

Comment: Are you guaranteed ordering in the list as shown in input, meaning that `manufacturer_id`s are at least grouped as show?

Comment: what do you mean by efficient? And what failed with your tried approach?

Comment: yup. either you will iterate through and create your objects (use a dictionary for efficiency by manufacturer_id. ) or you will write a groupby function or use a built in library.  this link would be useful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn No the arrangement is not ordered in input. It will be random

Comment: the ```model_number```s which have  ```0``` s in front of it cause the error ```SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers``` ? Can I remove the ```0```s

Comment: @coderoftheday Yes you can change the value. The given values are dummy

Comment: @GonzalesGokhan Thank you will try this approach.

Comment: @lucidbrot I need to create a set to store only the laptop manufacturer. Then create each instance of the manufacturer and add them to a dictionary. I was not sure if this approach satisfies time and space complexities

Comment: @ChandruJc In my experience it is often good enough to write code that is simple to write (less bugs) and to understand (easier to maintain) and only optimize for efficiency if it turns out to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
from more_itertools import bucket
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

laptop_list = [
{"manufacturer_id": 1 , "manufacturer_name": "Lenovo", "model_number": '000000', "model_name": "Legion"},
{"manufacturer_id": 2 , "manufacturer_name": "HP", "model_number": '0101010', "model_name": "pavillion"},
{"manufacturer_id": 1 , "manufacturer_name": "Lenovo", "model_number": '999999', "model_name": "Ideapad"},
{"manufacturer_id": 2 , "manufacturer_name": "HP", "model_number": '0202020', "model_name": "Inspiron"},
{"manufacturer_id": 1 , "manufacturer_name": "Lenovo", "model_number": '999999', "model_name": "Ideapad"},
{"manufacturer_id": 2 , "manufacturer_name": "HP", "model_number": '0202020', "model_name": "Inspiron"} ]

m_id = itemgetter('manufacturer_id')
bucketed = bucket(laptop_list, m_id)
result = []

for i in bucketed:
    d = {'model': []}

    for j in bucketed[i]:
        _d = j
        
        for k, v in sorted(j.items())[:2]:
            d[k] = v
            _d.pop(k)
        else:
            d['model'].append(_d)

    result.append(dict(sorted(d.items())))

pprint(result)
```

```
[{'manufacturer_id': 1,
  'manufacturer_name': 'Lenovo',
  'model': [{'model_name': 'Legion', 'model_number': '000000'},
            {'model_name': 'Ideapad', 'model_number': '999999'},
            {'model_name': 'Ideapad', 'model_number': '999999'}]},
 {'manufacturer_id': 2,
  'manufacturer_name': 'HP',
  'model': [{'model_name': 'pavillion', 'model_number': '0101010'},
            {'model_name': 'Inspiron', 'model_number': '0202020'},
            {'model_name': 'Inspiron', 'model_number': '0202020'}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictt = list(map(lambda x: {'manufacturer_id':x['manufacturer_id'],'manufacturer_name':x['manufacturer_name'] }, laptop_list))
no_duplicate_dict = [dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in dictt}]

sub_dict = list(map(lambda x: [x['manufacturer_id'], {'model_number':x['model_number'], 'model_name':x['model_name']}], laptop_list))

grouped_dict = [    [ID]+[[x[1] for x in sub_dict if x[0] == ID]] for ID in set([id[0] for id in sub_dict])   ]

list(map(lambda x: x.update( {'models' : [sub_dict[1][0-len(sub_dict[1])] for sub_dict in grouped_dict if x['manufacturer_id'] == sub_dict[0]] }), no_duplicate_dict))

print(no_duplicate_dict)

>>> [{'manufacturer_id': 2, 'manufacturer_name': 'HP', 'models': [{'model_number': 101010, 'model_name': 'pavillion'}]}, {'manufacturer_id': 1, 'manufacturer_name': 'Lenovo', 'models': [{'model_number': 0, 'model_name': 'Legion'}]}]
```

I made to sepearete list one with `manufacturer_id and manufacturer_name`  and another with `model_number and model_name`

I then added the sub list from `model_number and model_name` with the dictionaries in the list of ``````manufacturer_id and manufacturer_name`that matched up using`manufacturer_id``` as the key to match them

This line `no_duplicate_dict = [dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in dictt}]` just removed duplicate dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. I am posting my approach as well.

```
class LaptopNode:

    def __init__(self, manufacturer_id):
        self.manufacturer_name = None
        self.manufacturer_id = manufacturer_id
        self.child_models = []

    def add_child_device(self, child_model):
        self.child_models.append(child_model)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    modified_list = []

    # Remove duplicate parents
    parent_laptop_set = {laptop['manufacturer_id'] for laptop in laptop_list}

    # Create a instance for each parent
    laptop_instance_dictt = {manufacturer_id: LaptopNode(manufacturer_id) for manufacturer_id in parent_laptop_set}

    # Iterate through original list and map child models to parent
    for laptop in laptop_list:
        model = laptop_instance_dictt[laptop['manufacturer_id']]
        model.manufacturer_name = laptop['manufacturer_name']
        model.add_child_device({'model_name': laptop['model_name'], 'model_number': laptop['model_number']})

    for laptop_instance in laptop_instance_dictt.values():
        modified_list.append(
            {"manufacturer_id": laptop_instance.manufacturer_id, "manufacturer_name": laptop_instance.manufacturer_name,
             "models": laptop_instance.child_models})
    print(modified_list)
```