# Filtering a list of lists based on an index containing a common value

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 0.0, 6.0], [0.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 0.0, 6.0], [0.0, 0.0, 9.0], [0.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 0.0, 9.0]]
```

Each list within the global list represents a set of X,Y,Z coordinates for a point. I am trying to create a new number of lists (X number of lists) based on how many different Z coordinates there are. In this example, I would like to create 3 new lists because there are 3 different Z coordinates (3, 6 and 9). However, this code will also be used in instances where there could be any number of Z coordinates.

I tried the following code but it doesn't give the desired output:

```
for i in range(len(slabCoordList)-1):
if slabCoordList[i][2] == slabCoordList[i+1][2]:
    newList.append(slabCoordList[i])
```

I'm not sure how to split the lists based on the 2nd index of each list and I'm not sure how to create X number of new lists.

I would appreciate any help you could offer!

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired output in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very manual and non-sophisticated way of solving your problem, but it should do. It will convert your list to a Numpy matrix, create sublists based on the value on the third column (index 2), and return Numpy matrixes whose rows share the Z value.

```py
import numpy as np

l = [[0.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 0.0, 6.0], [0.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 0.0, 6.0], [0.0, 0.0, 9.0], [0.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 0.0, 9.0]]

new_lists = []
for z in np.unique(l[:, 2]):
    new_lists.append([x for x in l if x[2] == z])
```

Comment: Do you even need NumPy for this? You could use a set instead: `{x[2] for x in l}`

Comment: Numpy would be faster depending on the size of 'l'---though the append itself is quite slow too.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` has a `groupby` which allows you to pass a group `key` in this case a function that returns the last element of each list `x[-1]`.  Now we can use list comprehension to create groupings.

```
from itertools import groupby
l = [[0.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 0.0, 6.0], [0.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 0.0, 6.0], [0.0, 0.0, 9.0], [0.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 0.0, 9.0]]

[list(x) for _,x in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x[-1])]
```

Output

```
[[[0.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 0.0, 3.0]],
 [[0.0, 0.0, 6.0], [0.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 0.0, 6.0]],
 [[0.0, 0.0, 9.0], [0.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 0.0, 9.0]]]
```

Comment: Note that this requires `l` to be sorted

Comment: They are coordinates aren't they

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: They would be x,y,z

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the sub-lists. I'm taking about `l` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
l = [[0.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 0.0, 6.0], [0.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 0.0, 6.0], [0.0, 0.0, 9.0], [0.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 0.0, 9.0]]

d={}
for i in l:
  ind = i[2]
  if ind not in d:
    d[ind]=[]
  d[ind].append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input is always sorted, you could use `groupby` like in [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65470962/4518341). If not, you could use a dict:

```
d = {}
for coord in slabCoordList:
    z = coord[2]
    d.setdefault(z, []).append(coord)

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Output:

```
3.0 [[0.0, 0.0, 3.0], [0.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 24.0, 3.0], [24.0, 0.0, 3.0]]
6.0 [[0.0, 0.0, 6.0], [0.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 24.0, 6.0], [24.0, 0.0, 6.0]]
9.0 [[0.0, 0.0, 9.0], [0.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 24.0, 9.0], [24.0, 0.0, 9.0]]
```