# Merge Rows based on similar values in some columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

please I need help, I am recently started learning python. Please, how do I merge rows with the same “PatientID” and the same “Resource” as one with “StartDate” and “EndDate” as the average of the merged rows?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLrYG.png)

Comment: Do you only need these 4 columns or is there another column that you would like to keep too ?

Comment: can you give an example output in a good format?

Comment: Your ask seems like you're looking to group by `PatientId` and `Resource`, not "merge". However, the requested aggregates: average of `StartDate` and `EndDate` doesn't seem right. What will this inform you about the resource for the patient?

Comment: yes, I understand now that the average of StartDate and EndDate is not possible. @OluwafemiSule.

Comment: @exudong, I have added an image as an example of what I want to get, please check

Comment: you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749512/python-group-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `df` is the name for the `pandas.DataFrame` containing your data.

To get the earliest `StartDate` and `EndDate` of each patient's resource,  you can write:

```py
# Group by the 'PatientID' and 'Resource' columns
grouped_df =  df.groupby(['PatientID', 'Resource'])

# Select Earliest `StartDate` and `EndDate` from aggregate.
grouped_df = grouped_df.min(['StartDate', 'EndDate'])

# Remove levels from the index.
grouped_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```