# Add all duplicate values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
foo = [{'date':'01-08-2022', 'pre_val':90, 'cur_val':100},{'date':'02-08-2022', 'pre_val':70, 'cur_val':100},{'date':'01-08-2022', 'pre_val':60, 'cur_val':50}]
```

I would like to add all the duplicate day's values

```
bar = [{'date':'01-08-2022', 'pre_val':150, 'cur_val':150},{'date':'02-08-2022', 'pre_val':70, 'cur_val':100}]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Start by providing valid lists...

Comment: Please clarify what the output should look like

Comment: Hi, Im sorry I have updated the question

Comment: Let me clarify this a little more. Are you trying to loop through a list of data, find matching data and then move it into another list??? Does the data need to match 100%? or can a single key-value pair match? The question doesn't expose anything of use to any developer here please add more information.

Comment: the date key value should match, If date matches then need to add the pre_val and cur_val.

Comment: Your "dates" do not represent valid Python values. Please show what your data really looks like

Comment: The *foo* list contains two identical dates. Should they both be updated?

Comment: the values of that 2 identical dates get added.

Comment: @DeekshithHari, please use clear words as what is sample input and what is the expected output. As you can see, many devs are trying to help you; but are spending their efforts on wrong expectations. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Related: [Python group by](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3749512/8746648)

Comment: Thank you everyone. The quesion I question i wrote was bit confusing, and im sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = [{'date':'01-08-2022', 'pre_val':90, 'cur_val':100},
    {'date':'02-08-2022', 'pre_val':70, 'cur_val':100},
    {'date':'01-08-2022', 'pre_val':60, 'cur_val':50}]
bar = []
for i in foo:
    date, pre_val, cur_val = i.values()
    isupdate = False
    for d in bar:
        if d["date"] == date:
            d1 = {'pre_val':d["pre_val"] + pre_val, 
                'cur_val':d["cur_val"] + cur_val}
            d.update(d1)
            isupdate = True
    if not isupdate:
        bar.append(i)
```

Output:

```
[{'date': '01-08-2022', 'pre_val': 150, 'cur_val': 150}, {'date': '02-08-2022', 'pre_val': 70, 'cur_val': 100}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved without the need for additional module imports as follows:

```
foo = [{'date': '01-08-2022', 'pre_val': 90, 'cur_val': 100},
       {'date': '02-08-2022', 'pre_val': 70, 'cur_val': 100},
       {'date': '01-08-2022', 'pre_val': 60, 'cur_val': 50}]

bar = []

for f in foo:
    _date = f['date']
    for b in bar:
        if _date == b['date']:
            for k in 'pre_val', 'cur_val':
                b[k] += f[k]
            break
    else:
        bar.append(f)

print(bar)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'date': '01-08-2022', 'pre_val': 150, 'cur_val': 150}, {'date': '02-08-2022', 'pre_val': 70, 'cur_val': 100}]
```

Answer (score -1):

This can be very easily done using pandas grouping operations:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = [{'date':'01-08-2022', 'pre_val':90, 'cur_val':100},{'date':'02-08-2022', 'pre_val':70, 'cur_val':100},{'date':'01-08-2022', 'pre_val':60, 'cur_val':50}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>          date  pre_val  cur_val
>> 0  01-08-2022       90      100
>> 1  02-08-2022       70      100
>> 2  01-08-2022       60       50

df2 = df.groupby("date") \
  .agg( \
       pre_val=("pre_val", sum), \
       cur_val=("cur_val", sum), \
      ) \
  .reset_index()
>>          date  pre_val  cur_val
>> 0  01-08-2022      150      150
>> 1  02-08-2022       70      100

df2.set_index("date").T.to_dict()
>> {'01-08-2022': {'pre_val': 150, 'cur_val': 150}, '02-08-2022': {'pre_val': 70, 'cur_val': 100}}
```

Comment: This merges the two identical dates. What makes you think OP requires that? How does this answer the question of how to add the vales from *bar* to *foo*?